# Link (with redirects) opens in incognito or when open in new tab, or new page is explicitly declared. Doesn't work when just clicked

Tags: java, javascript, spring, http

What would the reasons be for a link failing in a 400 error when being clicked. The link also works in the other following situations

- Clicked open in new tab
- Clicked open in new window
- Clicked open in incognito or private

I've taken apart the requests, and when requesting each request path on its own, each URL appears to work.

The click link is invoked by Javascript on the front-end and makes requests to Java Spring back-end to push data to a RDb.

Could this be a header issue?

I cannot release the links or the code for this unfortunately due to its confidential nature, but can provide any publicly available information for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the request header length was too long.

Please see fix below:

http://www.iliachemodanov.ru/en/blog-en/13-tools/glassfish/24-long-urls-in-glassfish-en